# pivot_longer: create multiple columns of different types from multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to create `pivot_long` my data frame by creating 3 additional columns; `mean_stat`, `med_stat` & `sample` filled with their corresponding values.

Here's my strategy

1. `mean_stat` from `mean_stat.x, mean_stat.y, mean_stat`
2. `med_stat` from `med_stat.x, med_stat.y, med_stat`
3. `sample` from `sample.x, sample.y, sample`

Please is there a way i can accomplish this? i tried the code below but keep getting errors.

```
> data_head %>% pivot_longer(col= !c("seqnames",
+                             "start","end","strand",
+                             "pos","mgi_symbol",
+                             "ensembl_transcript_id_version",
+                             "ensembl_gene_id_version"), 
+                             names_to = c("mean_stat.x", "mean_stat.y","mean_stat",
+                             "med_stat.x", "med_stat.y", "med_stat",
+                             "sample.x","sample.y","sample"),
+                             values_to=c("mean_stat","med_stat","sample"))
Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! If you supply multiple names in `names_to` you must also supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

data looks like this

```
> dput(data_head)
structure(list(seqnames = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr6", class = "factor"), 
    start = c(6862382L, 6862382L, 6862383L, 6862383L, 6862427L, 
    6862427L), end = c(6862382L, 6862382L, 6862383L, 6862383L, 
    6862427L, 6862427L), strand = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("+", "-", "*"), class = "factor"), pos = c(6862382L, 
    6862382L, 6862383L, 6862383L, 6862427L, 6862427L), mean_stat.x = c(0.19792959917225, 
    0.19792959917225, 0.199321381221393, 0.199321381221393, 0.00406433693126574, 
    0.00406433693126574), med_stat.x = c(0.0165784049972236, 
    0.0165784049972236, 0.145539314543045, 0.145539314543045, 
    0.000704259313821343, 0.000704259313821343), sample.x = c("P_1", 
    "P_1", "P_1", "P_1", "P_1", "P_1"), mgi_symbol = c("Dlx6", 
    "Dlx6", "Dlx6", "Dlx6", "Dlx6", "Dlx6"), ensembl_transcript_id_version = c("ENSMUST00000160937.8", 
    "ENSMUST00000171311.7", "ENSMUST00000160937.8", "ENSMUST00000171311.7", 
    "ENSMUST00000160937.8", "ENSMUST00000171311.7"), ensembl_gene_id_version = c("ENSMUSG00000029754.13", 
    "ENSMUSG00000029754.13", "ENSMUSG00000029754.13", "ENSMUSG00000029754.13", 
    "ENSMUSG00000029754.13", "ENSMUSG00000029754.13"), mean_stat.y = c(0.000764852175246134, 
    0.000764852175246134, 0.394296327919949, 0.394296327919949, 
    0.00375821267875787, 0.00375821267875787), med_stat.y = c(0.000764852175246134, 
    0.000764852175246134, 0.394296327919949, 0.394296327919949, 
    0.00375821267875787, 0.00375821267875787), sample.y = c("P_2", 
    "P_2", "P_2", "P_2", "P_2", "P_2"), mean_stat = c(0.221987651899815, 
    0.221987651899815, 0.352667337885222, 0.352667337885222, 
    0.00892599647121971, 0.00892599647121971), med_stat = c(0.00799234148146299, 
    0.00799234148146299, 0.256276923247135, 0.256276923247135, 
    0.000752177507566287, 0.000752177507566287), sample = c("P_3", 
    "P_3", "P_3", "P_3", "P_3", "P_3")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide _usable data_ by using `dput(head(x))` to share the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to use the `".value"` sentinel in `names_to`. As the error says, you also have to use `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to say how you want to split up the column names. Using `names_sep` with `"."` as the separator:

```
library(tidyr)

data_head_long <- data_head %>%
  pivot_longer(
    matches("mean_stat|med_stat|sample"),
    names_to = c(".value", "xy"),
    names_sep = "\\."
  )
```

```
#> dplyr::select(data_head_long, seqnames, xy:sample)
# A tibble: 18 × 5
   seqnames xy    mean_stat med_stat sample
   <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
 1 chr6     x      0.198    0.0166   P_1   
 2 chr6     y      0.000765 0.000765 P_2   
 3 chr6     <NA>   0.222    0.00799  P_3   
 4 chr6     x      0.198    0.0166   P_1   
 5 chr6     y      0.000765 0.000765 P_2   
 6 chr6     <NA>   0.222    0.00799  P_3   
 7 chr6     x      0.199    0.146    P_1   
 8 chr6     y      0.394    0.394    P_2   
 9 chr6     <NA>   0.353    0.256    P_3   
10 chr6     x      0.199    0.146    P_1   
11 chr6     y      0.394    0.394    P_2   
12 chr6     <NA>   0.353    0.256    P_3   
13 chr6     x      0.00406  0.000704 P_1   
14 chr6     y      0.00376  0.00376  P_2   
15 chr6     <NA>   0.00893  0.000752 P_3   
16 chr6     x      0.00406  0.000704 P_1   
17 chr6     y      0.00376  0.00376  P_2   
18 chr6     <NA>   0.00893  0.000752 P_3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! btw can you please provide intuitive understanding of how `.value` works? i still don't get it even after looking at the tidy documentation and examples